# groupingBy with Boolean but add custom String as Key

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am having the below code and doing groupingBy based on boolean

```
Map<Boolean, List<Test>> products = testList
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::isValidUser));
```

I want to collect it as `Map<String, List<Test>` .

Based on the boolean value, want to add the custom key as "Valid" and "Invalid".

If the `isValidUser` true, want to add the key as "Valid", else key should be "Invalid"

Any possibility to do this in Java 11?

Note: without adding the String variable in Test class

Comment: if you want to group by boolean then use `partiioningBy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may do it using the ternary operator in the key classifier function in the `groupingBy` collector. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, List<Test>> products = testList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.isValidUser() ? "Valid" : "Invalid"));
```

Comment: Alternatively `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.partitioningBy( Test::isValidUser), m -> Map.of("Valid", m.get(true), "Invalid", m.get(false))))`